# Gentile Biography which Inspires

Tags: gentiles, books-generally, mussar-ethics

What is the jewish view on reading biographies of remarkable gentiles which one finds inspirational provided there is no apikorsus in the content.

Have come across a website about a certain person who led a remarkable life, dedicated herself to living the golden rule. Is it permitted to read this stuff if it significantly inspires one to improve his conduct? or is it better to stay away

Comment: http://rabbisedley.blogspot.com/2008/12/ben-franklin-and-cheshbon-hanefesh.html

Comment: @DoubleAA I've always thought it was interesting that Cheshbon HaNefesh is based on Benjamin Franklin, considering that Franklin himself was a notorious plagiarizer of sayings of Chazal (and Tanach, too).

Comment: I don't think anyone can be called a plagiarizer of tanach. That's like accusing someone of breathing for free.

Comment: @SethJ Maybe so. I was sort of thinking that myself (hence the parentheses), but he didn't let on that the quotes were from the Bible. I suppose it could've been considered obvious though, especially in those days when (I assume) a higher percentage of the population could quote chapter and verse.

Comment: The Cheshbon Hanefesh is an example of the USE of a gentile work. but maybe this is not permitted. is there any source for whether it is permitted?

Comment: @R.Sebag Are you speculating if Cheshbon Hanefesh is permitted? Because many great rabbis have endorsed it.

Comment: no. just suggesting that it was taken from Ben Franklin and that this was bad, but not bad enough to asur the book due to the public benefit from it. but its asur to do this for oneself at least lechatchila

Comment: Rambam writes in introduction to avos קבל האמת ממי שאמרו and quotes from Aristotle in the Moreh and from Greeks in Hilchos kiddush hachodesh. The gemara cites דמה בן נתינה as the paradigm of kibud av.

Comment: @Yoni דמא בן נתינה is not the paradigm, rather the extent: עד היכן. Halacha is not mechuyav to be מפסיד ממון. And just in case...yes מניעת רווח is a הפסד, see the Rosh in moed koton גבי חול המועד

Comment: Iyov, according to the opinion that he was not Jewish, is a gentile biography

Comment: @Fred, As Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) the modern taboo of Plagiarism is an invention of the 18th Century, so at most Benjamin Franklin was a bit out of date.

Comment: @Mefaresh For kibud av one IS (AKAIK) obligated to lose opportunities for making money (Just is not obligated to spend money). But your comment is off-topic, anyway

Comment: Agav "the real George Washington" was an incredibly inspiring bio.

Answer (score 1):

I think there would be no problem with this, especially if it is fully appropriate and they adhered to Jewish values (even though they weren't Jewish themselves). There are incredible and interesting gentiles out there, like Oskar Schindler and Benjamin Franklin.

Besides, I am not aware of anything that says that reading history is *asur*, and biographies are history, with some added inspiration.

Comment: While your opinion is perhaps interesting, none of us know you that we should value it at all. Try [edit]ing to cite some sources for your ideas so we can learn from them.

Comment: Bnjamin Franklin was infamous for womanizing.

Comment: FYI there are those that prohibit reading history books based on SA OC 307:16, unless there's some toeles involved (like you mentioned, inspiration etc.)

Answer (score 1):

See gra on shir hashirim 1, 3 who explains that akum'z are able to assimilate the kedushah of torah shebichsav but not torah shebaalpeh.

Therefore at best you would be left with literalistic views of right, wrong and self-sacrifice if you absorbed the lessons in that website.